# Which makes Lie groupoids so nice?

Tags: ct.category-theory, internal-groupoids, lie-groupoids

This is a continuation of [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81506/compare-three-2-categories-of-lie-groupoids).

A) Morphisms in (1') are basically [internal anafunctors](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/anafunctor), their compositions heavily use (and only) pullback/limit.

B) Bibundles in (2) are basically special kind [internal profunctores](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/print/internal+profunctor), their compositions heavily use quotient/coend/colimit.

We know that (1') and (2) are equivalent, this is a bit surprising since limit and colimit are usually very different notions. My question is which categorical properties make this true? Thanks.

Comment: You should also ask, what categorical properties allow you to DEFINE composition in (2)? Probably this has the same answer.

Comment: @DavidCarchedi I suppose the composition may come from the fact that surjective submersion admits local sections.

Comment: @DavidCarchedi This is addressed in http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5220v1